# In JPA, why does CriteriaBuilder let me build unsound predicates between unrelated types?

Tags: jpa-2.0, eclipselink, hibernate-criteria, querydsl

I am curious as to why it is possible, with the `CriteriaBuilder` class of JPA 2, to create such queries. Suppose I have a `User` class with a persisted `String` called `name` as attribute. Why can I write this?

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = mgr.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<User> crit = builder.createQuery(User.class);
Root<User> user = crit.from(User.class);                     // 1
crit.select(user)
    .where(builder.equal(user.get(User_.name), 2.5));        // 2
```

First, at Marker 1: Why must I indicate `User.class` again? Isn't my CriteriaQuery supposed to know I'm interested in users anyway? Doesn't it break type safety to possibly inject another class here?

Second, at Marker 2: The `name` property is a `String`. Why can I compile nonsense like this, comparing a `String` with a double? In other words, why is the signature of the called `equal` method this:

```
public Predicate equal(Expression<?> x, Object y)
```

instead of a presumably more type safe version as follows?

```
public <T> Predicate equal(Expression<T> x, T y)
```

Would other query frameworks like [Querydsl](http://www.querydsl.com) provide a better solution to this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the typesafe aspects of the JPA 2 Criteria API were added at a quite late point of the specification process. That's why it doesn't feel consistent.

Querydsl is more concise than the JPA 2 Criteria API and also more typesafe. Querydsl uses fluent builders instead of a factory class for predicate creation, so the equivalent method can be found here http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/2.8.0/apidocs/com/mysema/query/types/expr/SimpleExpression.html#eq%28T%29

I am the maintainer of Querydsl, so this answer is biased.

Comment: I’ve just had a closer look at Querydsl and it sure looks very, very good. I love it. The only downside is the number of dependencies. Do I really need all of them? Is there a document somewhere that says which jars are needed for which features?

Comment: Which dependencies are you concerned about? There is no document declaring which dependency is used for which feature.

Comment: Do I need stuff like antlr, asm, glib, ecj, guava, validation-api if I just want to have the nice JPA queries?

Comment: The compile scope dependency set is smaller than that. You can set the querydsl-apt dependency to provided and exclude cglib and asm if you don't need the proxy features.

Comment: OK, I’ll check that, thanks. I had just directly downloaded the archive and assumed that everything was needed.

Answer (score 2):

specific on JPA you can use also [Object Query](http://www.objectquery.org) or [Torpedo Query](http://www.torpedoquery.org)(but this is specialized on HQL) that not needs compile time model generation. anyway [QueryDsl](http://www.querydsl.com/) is one of the first to implement typesafe query